# Does the `mmcif/pdb` format store atomic coordinates in units of Ångstrom, nanometers or something else?

Tags: pdb, 3d-structure, distance

I was surprised as to how hard it was to find a reference on this among the docs.

Does the Protein Data Bank [mmcif/pdb-x](https://mmcif.wwpdb.org/) archival format use Angstrom to specify cartesian x,y,z coordinates of atoms or something else or abstract units (perhaps defined per each `mmcif` `_data` frame?

How is the origin of the grid calculated -- for crystallographers out there?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From google I got this as first hit :

[PDB_format_1992.pdf](https://cdn.rcsb.org/wwpdb/docs/documentation/file-format/PDB_format_1992.pdf) :

[image]

Hopefully they keept the same Unit of measurement during the data/file format evolution/extension

It seems the case for `mmcif` [Data Item _atom_site.Cartn_x](https://mmcif.wwpdb.org/dictionaries/mmcif_pdbx_v40.dic/Items/_atom_site.Cartn_x.html) :

[image]

Some history here :

[The Protein Data Bank: a historical perspective](https://journals.iucr.org/a/issues/2008/01/00/sc5004/sc5004.pdf) , [The Protein Data Bank](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC102472/pdf/gkd090.pdf)

AND :

```
PY  - 1971
DA  - 1971/10/01
TI  - Crystallography: Protein Data Bank
JO  - Nature New Biology
SP  - 223
EP  - 223
VL  - 233
IS  - 42
SN  - 2058-1092
UR  - https://doi.org/10.1038/newbio233223b0
DO  - 10.1038/newbio233223b0
ID  - ref1
ER  -
```

[image]

About the axis origin CHARMM-GUI has a nice introductory lesson to PDB format (see ***CRYTST1 Record*** Section) [Lesson 1: Introduction to PDB Format](https://charmm-gui.org/?doc=lecture&module=pdb&lesson=1)

and stolen from the web, free part of an old book :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, pip. Missed the "angstroms" part when browsing through the spec. The paper and book references are very much appreciated.